# How to get vault version with java api?

Tags: java, spring-cloud-vault-config

What is the proper way to get Vault version with java api? If there's not an api call what is the rest call? There is no /status call. I am scanning spring-vault-core-1.1.2.RELEASE-sources.jar for keywords "status" and version".

Answer (score 0):

You can obtain the version through the Template API by using the system operations interface:

```
VaultOperations operations = …;
VaultHealth health = operations.opsForSys().health();
String version = health.getVersion();
```

See also:

- [Javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-vault/docs/1.1.2.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/vault/core/VaultSysOperations.html#health--)